# Question about force experienced by an object in fluid with pressure distribution given?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics

I have a fluid flowing towards a sink such that its pressure distribution as a function of distance from the sink is given by
$$\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2},$$

where $x$ is the distance from the sink and $p$ is the pressure.
The space around sink is spherically symmetric and hence $x$ represents spatial coordinates and $P_0$ is fluid pressure at infinite distance.

If I have an object in fluid which is small enough to not disturb the pressure gradient, how much force will it experience?

PS: please do not remove it thinking its a HW question. It is not!

Comment: How is $P_0$ the pressure at infinite distance?  I don't think you can integrate this equation to infinity, since the constant term will diverge. What is $p$? Can you be a bit more clear? Where did you get this equation from?

Comment: Fixed it. $P_0$ term comes after integration under assumption that fluid pressure is constant far away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the object is a cube of side $b$ (I am making this assumption, since you did not mention anything about the shape of the object and that simplifies the calculations) at a distance of $l$ away from the sink. Consider the pressure on two opposite sides of the cube. One facing the sink and the other away from it. That means that the pressure difference between one side and the other will be

$$\Delta p=\int_l^{l+b} \frac{dp}{dx}  dx=\int_l^{l+b} \frac{1}{x^2} dx=-\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) \Bigg|_{l}^{l+b}=\frac{1}{l}-\frac{1}{l+b}=\frac{b}{l(l+b)}.$$

So the force acting on the cube is
$F= A \Delta p= b^2 \Delta p = \frac{b^3}{l(l+b)},$

where $A=b^2$ is the cross-sectional area of the cube. Since $b \ll l$, we can approximate $F$ as
$$F \sim b \left(\frac{b}{l}\right)^2 + O\left( \frac{b}{l}\right)^3.$$

Effectively, the force goes down as $\frac{1}{x^2}$ as you move away from the sink with a proportionality constant that depends on the geometry of the object.

Comment: Would be glad if you can cite the source too. I'm pretty sure its somewhere in fluids chapter but cant find it

Comment: @user146021 Possibly, but I didn't use one so don't know what to cite. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure-gradient_force) is the most relevant thing I could find.